# How to remove all undefined keys from a javascript array (hopefully when creating the array?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach, each

I have placed my frustrations into a jsfiddle to observe here: http://jsfiddle.net/8ShFr/1/

```
var brand_new_array = new Array();
brand_new_array[10] = "random array value";
alert('why does this array have a length of ' + brand_new_array.length + '???');
```

I am doing some calculations client side that require me to set javascript array keys of 1M+ in number.

Not knowing exactly what that number is demands that I iterate through the first 1M+ empty array values before getting to an array key that holds data.

I simply want to set a single large key value for a javascript array without creating a bunch of empty keys before it?

I am using jQuery.each to iterate over the array, and it keeps going through `array[0]`, `array[1]`, `array[2]`, etc... when I only set `array[123125]` for example.

Comment: Can somebody please explain to me what @Mega just did to edit my question? I can't see any changes?

Comment: He added some formatting to the variable examples at the bottom of your post. New users tend to suggest edits more frequently with the goal of attaining the +2 reputation so it may seem a little minor. Overall it is harmless though, don't look at it as a negative :) If you click on the "edited 6 hours ago" portion it will link to the revision history and if you feel strongly about it, you can click rollback and it will go to your original version.

Answer (score 6):

Just `filter` out the `undefined`s.

```
brand_new_array = brand_new_array.filter(function(n){return n !== undefined});
```

Comment: Please include a description and why this answer would be better than the existing answers. The code on itself is not really a complete answer to this question.

Comment: @Joeytje50 I've added some text to my answer ;-)

Comment: How about [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility)? How will it handle values that evaluate as `false` such as `0`?

Comment: According to that [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility), IE8 and lower don't though, and [IE8 still has a 6.8% usage share](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201212-201312). Also, I just tried this, and it also filters out `0` and `false`, and that was not part of the question. I'm sure it wasn't OP's intention to also strip out `0` from the array.

Comment: Please, stop it. I'm not a student on an exam.

Comment: Yours is my favorite answer, thank you Oleg. Don't mind the heckling. But, the real question is, does it work in IE6?

Comment: Sadly, I have no possibility to check that. IE provides backward capability mode only from 7th version.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the length being 10 is that an array's length is set to the largest index number in the array. However, this does not mean there are 9 other values in there because in javascript an array is at its base an object.

The length is just a property in the object. Arrays in javascript are at their core objects (Array Object **<sup>1</sup>**). They merely act like arrays through an api.

> "Whenever a property is added whose name is an array index, the length property is changed, if necessary, to be one more than the numeric value of that array index" **<sup>1</sup>**

**<sub>[1. ECMAScript Language Specification 15.4 Array Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4)</sub>**

Comment: In this case, you probably want to simply use an object instead of an array and iterate using `for..in`. If you're not going to use it as an array, an object with enumerable (numeric) properties will do just fine.

Comment: So, where is the answer how to remove `undefined` elements?

Comment: @Oleg - You missed the point. There is no removing the undefined elements because they simply are not there. If you check, it will say undefined because nothing is present, just like if you check an undeclared variable it will say undefined. However, if you iterate from 0 to length (length being 1 + the top index of the array), then it will seem like you encountered undefined elements when in reality there was nothing there to begin with. js allows you to attempt to access an array in situations where stricter languages would throw an out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to just use an object with strings for keys (the keys can be the toString() of Numbers, which will happen automatically if you try to use numbers).

```
var sparse_array_obj = {};
sparse_array_obj[10003210234] = 4; // Fair dice roll
sparse_array_obj[5] = 17; // Truly random number
sparse_array_obj[900] = Math.random(); // Pseudorandom number

for(var i in sparse_array_obj) 
    console.log(sparse_array_obj[i]);
```

The downside is that Javascript provides no guarantees about the iteration order through an object (since its keys are unordered by definition). There are however ways around this, such as:

```
// Sort the keys in numeric order
var sorted_keys = Object.keys(sparse_array_obj).sort(function(a, b){ return a - b; });
for(var i = 0; i < sorted_keys.length; i++)
    console.log(sparse_array_obj[sorted_keys[i]]);
```

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) needs to be [shimmed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill) in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var brand_new_array = new Array();
brand_new_array[10] = "random array value";

var result = brand_new_array.filter(function(e) { return e != undefined;})[0];
alert(brand_new_array.indexOf(result));
```

Comment: please add more than juse code, describe what your code is doing

Answer (score 1):

Travis J is right. The array in your example only contains one entry, but your use of `jQuery.each()` is making you think there are 10 entries because it iterates from 0 up to the highest index number of the array (defines the length). This is from the `jQuery.each()` API documentation.

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, **from 0 to length-1**. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

Going back to your example:

```
var brand_new_array = new Array();
brand_new_array[10] = "random array value";
```

This will result in only one `console.log` output:

```
for(var i in brand_new_array) 
  console.log(brand_new_array[i]);
```

This will result in 10 `console.log` outputs:

```
$(brand_new_array).each( function(i,e) { console.log(e) })
```

Similarly, this will result in 10 `console.log` outputs:

```
for (var i=0;i<brand_new_array.length;i++)
  console.log(brand_new_array[i]);
```

If you really want to stick with using `.each()` then you can skip the undefined indices like so:

```
$(brand_new_array).each( function(i,e) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)){ console.log(e) } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the falsy items - including undifined:

```
var a=[1,2,"b",0,{},"",NaN,3,undefined,null,5];
var b=a.filter(Boolean); // [1,2,"b",{},3,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

The length is `11` because the index starts at `0`.

1. `x[0] = undefined`
2. `x[1] = undefined`
3. `x[2] = undefined`
4. `x[3] = undefined`
5. `x[4] = undefined`
6. `x[5] = undefined`
7. `x[6] = undefined`
8. `x[7] = undefined`
9. `x[8] = undefined`
10. `x[9] = undefined`
11. `x[10] = "random array value"`